# What do you think about ??= operator in C#?

Tags: c#, operators, null-coalescing-operator, null-coalescing

Do you think that C# will support something like ??= operator?

Instead of this:

```
if (list == null)
  list = new List<int>();
```

It might be possible to write:

```
list ??= new List<int>();
```

Now, I could use (but it seems to me not well readable):

```
list = list ?? new List<int>();
```

Comment: That would be cool!  Not sure if it supports it... but yes, i like it!

Comment: This idea suggestion makes my Ruby parts tingle warmly. (See the Ruby `||=` operator.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have always wanted something like this. I would use it far more often than the `??` by itself.

What I REALLY want, though, is a form of operator that lets you dereference the object only if non null. To replace this:

```
    int count = (list != null)? list.Count : 0
```

with something like this:

```
    int count = list??.Count : 0
```

Which would be especially useful for me with long chains of references (bad design, I know), but for example

```
    int count = foo??.bar??.baz??.list??.Count : 0
```

This isn't currently possible with `??` because you can only say "assign to foo, or an alternative if null" but not "assign to a *property* of foo, or an alternative if null."

Comment: While I would agree, I think this goes against the way C# works in general. It reminds me a lot more of message-passing languages like Obj-C, where [list count]; would return null instead of firing a null exception error. In C#, it makes the syntax a lot more confusing, especially because in this case you'd almost always want to use it.

Comment: of course I agree, like anything, it can be dangerous in the wrong hands. I'm in no way suggesting that this substitute for error handling by just ignoring all null references. But there are some cases where null is perfectly acceptable, and you have a valid alternate value to use in that case.

Comment: This is a frequently requested feature. We're considering it.

Comment: I would suggest rather foo?.bar?.baz ... There will be less mess:) and it will be compatible with save navigation in Groovy: http://groovy.codehaus.org/Statements#Statements-Safenavigation

Answer (score 16):

Personally I think only the second expansion makes sense (in terms of keeping along the same line as `+=` etc):

```
list = list ?? new List<int>();
```

but to be honest I find it a little bit unnecessary. People usually "get" `i += 5;`, but tend to have a problem with null-coalescing (`??`). Add a null-coalescing-assignment operator and... well, I don't see it ending well.

Personally I favor the original code:

```
if(list == null) { list = new List<int>(); }
....
```

Also - consider: in all the other `+=`, `-=` etc - the right hand side is always evaluated. In this case it wouldn't be (in some cases). That adds even more confusion. By which I mean:

```
i += SomethingCriticalThatMustBeCalled(); // fine - always runs
j ??= SomethingElseCriticalThatMustBeCalled(); // is this run? if j != null?
```

Comment: I agree. It's choice between speed of writing and readability. Readability wins every time.

Comment: I agree that readability is highly valuable, but I find the ??= operator to be fairly easy to grasp (then again, I like haskell so maybe I'm used to arbitrary operators).

But I don't think Marc's second example is a very good one.  You shouldn't be running critical code as a side-effect of a += anyway, so it's very contrived.

Answer (score 4):

A trick I found somewhere here on stackoverflow was to do something like this...

```
private List<string> myList;
public List<string> MyProp 
{
    get { return myList ?? (myList= new List<string>()); }
}
```

... you maybe able to use similar lazy eval in your code.

Answer (score 3):

I like it - it is a nice, succinct way to express a lazy-loading expression.  Whether or not it gets added to language is another thing altogether - as [Eric Lippert loves to point out](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/06/22/why-doesn-t-c-implement-top-level-methods.aspx), new features require significant amounts of work to implement and as such they must contribute a significant net positive to the language in order to be included.

Comment: Indeed, I'm not seeing a huge benefit here. I'm slightly surprised that a "null coalescing with assignment" operator wasn't added when ?? was added, but it really doesn't add a whole lot of power.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I read your question wrong, that operator does exist in C#: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224(VS.80).aspx